# -React Native, what is the way of passing state data from A.js to B.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am looking for the way of passing state data from A.js to B.js

> > so I want to retrieve  "DEF " as title[1] from A.js to B.js

A.js

```
export default class A extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        title: ["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
    };
}
render(){return(<Text>{this.state.title[1]}</Text>)}
module.exports = A;
```

B.js

```
import {A} from "./A"  
export default class B extends Component {
render(){return(<Text>{A.state.title[1]?? // not sure about this part 
 }</Text>)}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom for you :

```
import {B} from './B'
export default class A extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        title: ["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
    };
}
render(){return(<B titlePropForB={this.state.title})}
module.exports = A;


export default class B extends Component {
render(){
console.log(this.props.titlePropForB);
return(<Text>{this.props.titlePropForB[1]}</Text>)}
}
```

Comment: log statement that you see in B.js prints "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) to pass data between components.

Add the `props` in your parent you want to pass.

```
export default class A extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props = {
        title: ["ABC","DEF","GHI"]
    };
}
render(){return(<Text>{this.props.title}</Text>)}
module.exports = A;
```

Access them in the child.

```
import {A} from "./A"  
export default class B extends Component {}
render(){return(<Text>{this.props.data[1]}</Text>)}}
```

[This](https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/blob/master/props-vs-state.md) is a good reference discussing the differences between `props` and `state`.

Answer (score 0):

refer to my answer here [Passing Props to Screens in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48779200/passing-props-to-screens-in-react-native) .

passing props within different components has an alternative way, that is by using Redux library for managing app state. it is simple and easy to understand.